# How to create Dojo Table with Header

Tags: dojo

How can i create a table view using dojo controls.

For Example, I would like to create a table using dojo control that looks like this HTML Table.

```
<table border="0" style=" border:1px #000000 solid">
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Enabled</th>
            <th>On Trial</th>
            <th>Banned</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>50</td>        
            <td>30</td>        
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
```

Please let me know if you know anything.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do is wrap the HTML in a Dojo component. For example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View"> 

  //HTML Table && other dojo components

</div>
```

Does this help?